# node-red use several sources to build http post request

Tags: node.js, file, node-red, payload

I am new to node-red and I am confused with the "message payload flow system".

I want to send a POST request that contains, among other params, files into the request payload. These files should be in an array called "files".

I read my files from my file system, this works fine, but in the function node, how do I build my POST payload?

So far I have this:
[image]

The problem is that the payload contains both files and I can't find a way to get them separately. How can I retrieve both my files, separately, into the `BUILD-POST-REQ` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core Join node can be used to combine the output of parallel input streams. It has a number of modes that control how many input messages it will collect together.

[image]

These include a count of messages.

You can also choose how it combines the input messages, this can be as an array or as an object using the `msg.topic` as the key to the incoming `msg.payload`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found A solution. But I don't know if this is a best practice. Feel free to correct me!

[image]

The idea is that after each file read, I store it in a new property of the `msg` object and then can access it later in the flow.

Comment: Look at the join node

Comment: You should put it as an answer. @hardillb

Comment: Oh I did it. Works fine and it is exactly what I wanted!